# How do I use a PHP Short Code from custom field as an href link on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

On my wordpress page (which I will use as a template to duplicate) I need to use a custom field 'dropbox' as an href url.

I created a PHP Code Snippet (shortcode) to use as a replacement for the url: [xyz-ips snippet="dropbox"]

Here is the PHP within the shortcode:

```
<?php the_field('dropbox'); ?>
```

Here is the code on the page:

```
<a href="[xyz-ips snippet=" dropbox"]"="" target="_new">download the documents</a>
```

This short code will not pass the url from custom field to the href.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From where the link for short code comes? Please add the source code of short code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there is a specific way to call url custom fields (ACF).  I inserted the below code into a PHP Code shortcode.  This worked like a charm!

```
    <?php 

$link = get_field('dropbox');

if( $link ): ?>

    <a class="button" href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_new">download documents</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shortcode should be working if it's as you describe, but you should note shortcodes need to `return` values, not `echo` them. You didn't post the code you're using to register it, so I can only assume you're echoing content instead of returning it.

With that said,
I would just make the shortcode echo out the whole entire link, that way you have a bit more granular control over the whole thing:

```
add_shortcode( 'xyz-ips-link', function( $atts ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'snippet' => 'dropbox',
        'text'    => 'Download the Documents', 
        'target'  => '_new',
    ), $atts ) );


    $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="%s">%s</a>', get_field( $snippet ), $target, $text );

    return $link;
});
```

This will let you just use `[xyz-ips-link]` anywhere in your content,

or `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[xyz-ips-link]' ); ?>` in your page templates.

It also gives you more granular control over the content of the link, such as `[xyz-ips-link snippet="dropbox" text="Some Alternative Text"]`.

You'll also note I'm using [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead of [`the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/). WordPress (and ACF) both have `get_` functions that return a variable for you to use, and `the_` functions which get **and output** the variable by default.

You can see an example of this code [**here**](https://xhynk.com/content-mask/wpse-answer/so-52655773-example/), Note:I don't have ACF installed, so I replaced the `href` attribute)

Comment: Tried this and it was a no go.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what isn't working? You can clearly see the code working in the example link I added, so I'm interested to see what you're seeing.

Comment: Sure.  It was just going to "www.sitename.com/[xyz-ips%20snippet=" (broken link to self site instead of dropbox link.     Anyhow, the issue was resolved using this php in shortcode: `<?php 

$link = get_field('dropbox');

if( $link ): ?>

    <a class="button" href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_new">download documents</a>

<?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try it may work for you .

```
echo do_shortcode('dropbox');
```

Comment: Hi.   I used `<?php echo do_shortcode('dropbox'); ?>`  and it will go to www.sitename.com/[xyz-ips%20snippet=  which produces a 404 Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$dropdown = get_the_field('dropbox');
echo do_shortcode($dropbox);
```

OR

```
$dropdown = get_field('dropbox');
echo do_shortcode($dropbox);
```